# Lambda Calculus simplification

Tags: math, logic, lambda-calculus, reduction

Below is the lambda expression which I am finding difficult to reduce i.e. I am not able to understand how to go about this problem.

(λmn(λsz.ms(nsz)))(λsz.sz)(λsz.sz)

I am lost with this.

if anyone could lead me in the right direction that would be much appreciated

Comment: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place to ask. StackOverflow is for source code related questions! What did you read about lambda calculus?

Comment: Rather http://cs.stackexchange.com is the right place for this question. http://cstheory.stackexchange.com is for research level questions.